# Unpublished PhD work and unresponsive advisor

Tags: publications, ethics

I finished my PhD two years ago. However, my advisor left academia one year before I defended. I finished my research and successfully defended it (obviously), and have a good draft of my paper, but my advisor is completely inaccessible and has seemingly no interest in it (otherwise he would have answered me or contacted me). Is this work lost forever, meaning I cannot publish it without his consent?

Comment: In what ways have you tried contacting your advisor? If he deserves to be a co-author it's worth trying a phone call, and not just sticking with a work e-mail address he might not have access to anymore.

Comment: We had some contact after he left . His wife (a professor too) helped me shape the manuscript but it came to a point she was ok with the result. However, he does not answer his email or phone. Many people try to contact him but they end up contacting me since they know i was his grad student. He is the kind of person who cannot be bothered unless he wants something. I could deal with his wife but I need an answer from him.

Comment: In that case I'd probably take Buffy's approach, and also CC his wife on the email.

Comment: Especially since his wife has had some part in helping you to this point she seems like quite a reasonable person to contact about this, particularly if all you need is his approval.

Answer (score 6):

Unless he is truly a co-author and collaborator, beyond supervision, then you can publish it on your own. Advising doesn't automatically imply co-authorship in most fields. If he must be a co-author for ethical reasons, then prepare the paper with him as co-author and send a copy along to him stating that you intend to submit it to "xyzzy" unless you hear any objections. Of course this gives the advisor a sort of veto, but a co-author would have that in any case.

Within the paper, thank him for his help, as well, I think. Thank him when you send the paper to him as well, of course.

Comment: Thanks. I do consider him a co-author since he provided the funds after he left to continue this research and he provided the isolates I analyzed, and did some intial work with them. If I send him a request to find any objections and he doesn't reply, is that enough for me to take the lead and submit it for publication?

Comment: @J.Doe Note that funding a project does not alone constitute being worthy of authorship in many cases.

Comment: @J.Doe, say it nicely, but just inform him that the paper is about to be submitted without objection. One thing he might object to is co-authorship. In that case, just submit under your own name. But wait a bit before submitting. You can always make changes later as part of the publication process.

Comment: @Vladhagen. It is a little more complicated than that. Having funding for a project usually means that the (general) ideas of the research were contributed by the person who got the grant. This is often worth more than the people carrying out the research care to admit, but of course it is hard to say if this applies in this case without further information.

Comment: He did indeed conceive the project in general, he wrote the grant and was awarded the funds.